# php displays blank page while photo upload

Tags: php, sql

The following script adds a record to the database, but does not upload an image if I add:

```
if (isset($_FILES["logo"]["name"]))
```

However, *without* the `if`, it displays blank page.

I am unable to understand where the problem is. There are no error messages displayed.

```
<?php
include_once("user_status.php");
if ($is_admin == false){
header('location: ' .base_url(). 'index.php/admin/login');
}
if (isset($_POST["name"])){
$name = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9,]#i', '', $_POST["name"]);
$desc = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9,<>.]#i', '', $_POST["desc"]);
$developers = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9,;]#i', '', $_POST["developers"]);
$cat = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9,]#i', '', $_POST["cat"]);
$platform = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9,]#i', '', $_POST["platform"]);
$licence = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9,]#i', '', $_POST["licence"]);
$link = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9,//.:]#i', '', $_POST["link"]);

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM softwares WHERE name =         
'$name' LIMIT 1");
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
    {
        $totalCount = $row["COUNT(id)"];
        if ($totalCount > 0){

        header('location: ' .base_url(). 'index.php/admin/add-software?    
error=already-added');
        } else {



        $fileName = $_FILES["logo"]["name"];
        $db_file_name = $fileName;
        //$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["logo"]["tmp_name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'], '' .base_url().  
 '/assets/img/logo/' . $fileName . '');

        $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO softwares(name, description,  
 licence, developers, category, platform, link, logo) VALUES  
 ('$name','$desc','$licence','$developers','$cat','$platform',
 '$link','$db_file_name')");
        header('location: ' .base_url(). '/index.php/admin/view-softwares');
        exit();

        }
 }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: *blank page* means something is broken. Add these lines `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your PHP script and see if it yields any error or not.

Comment: Have you looked in the log file? How is your server set up? There is almost certainly an error being emitted somewhere.

Comment: Instead of flailing about with `preg_replace()` you should use [proper parameterized prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: "does not upload an image if I add..." I guess telling us where you added it would be a good start, as well as following the suggestions about error reporting.